# Unable to Access DynamoDB Item's Map attribute values with ExpressionFilter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following item in my DynamoDB table:

```
{
  "quid" : {
    "S":"87CEE4F1-5458-4A65-A3F5-1837A353B14D"
  },
  "objectType" : {
    "S":"event"
  },
  "document" : { 
    "M" : {
      "externalID" : {
        "S" : "12-34-567890"
      },
      "eventFormat" : {
        "N" : "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to access that item with the following javascript code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2"
});
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
  TableName : "events",
  FilterExpression : "document.eventFormat = :nForm",
  ExpressionAttributeValues : {":nForm":{"N":"0"}}
}

docClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
})
```

When I remove the FilterExpression and ExpressionAttributesValues, I get a full scan of my table successfully, and get to see all items contained within. When I add the FilterExpression and the ExpressionAttributesValues, I don't get any results back.

Any help figuring out how to filter my scan by either the externalID or the eventFormat would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below `params`. The data type is not required in `ExpressionAttributeValues` for scalar numeric values. This worked as expected for me.

```
var params = {
        TableName: "events",    
        FilterExpression: "document.eventFormat = :nForm",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":nForm": 0
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks notionquest! This did exactly whatw I needed! Many many thanks!